# how do I make install.packages return an error if an R package cannot be installed?

Tags: r

`install.packages()` returns a warning if a package cannot be installed (for instance, if it is unavailable); for example:

```
install.packages("notapackage")
```

(**EDIT**: I'd like to throw an error regardless of the reason the package cannot be installed, not just this example case of a missing package).

I am running the `install.packages` command in a script, and I would like it to trigger a proper error and exit execution.  I don't see an obvious option inside `install.packages` for handling this behavior.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Check with `available.packages()` first?

Comment: Terrible terrible terrible solution with text matching `install.package2 <- function(...){ifelse(any(grepl("Warning", capture.output(install.packages(...)))), 1, 0)}` and `cake.installer("cake"); cake.installer("lmtest")`

Comment: @Vlo yeah, my thoughts too. Perhaps we can do better with `withCallingHandlers()`...

Answer (score 13):

Having just solved this for myself, I noted that install.packages() results in calling library(thepackage) to see it its usable.

I made a R script that installs the given packages, uses `library` on each to see if its loadable, and if not calls `quit` with a non-0 status.

I call it `install_packages_or_die.R`

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

packages = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

for (l in packages) {

    install.packages(l, dependencies=TRUE, repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/');

    if ( ! library(l, character.only=TRUE, logical.return=TRUE) ) {
        quit(status=1, save='no')
    }
}
```

Use it like this in your Dockerfile. I'm grouping them in useful chunks to try and make reasonable use of Docker build cache.

```
ADD install_packages_or_die.R /

RUN Rscript --no-save install_packages_or_die.R profvis devtools memoise

RUN Rscript --no-save install_packages_or_die.R memoise nosuchpackage
```

Disclaimer: I do not consider myself an R programmer at all currently, so there may very well be better ways of doing this.

Comment: I have been fighting this all day.  Thank you for including this!  

Wouldn't another way to do it be something like:
RUN R -e "install_packages_or_die <- function (pkgs, lib=.libPaths(),repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/') {
  for (l in pkgs) {
    
    install.packages(l, dependencies=TRUE, repos=repos);
    
    if ( ! library(l, character.only=TRUE, logical.return=TRUE) ) {
      quit(status=1, save='no')
    }
  }
}
install_packages_or_die (pkgs =c('profviz','devtools'))"
```

Comment: the RUN R -e "..."

would let you embed the function in the Dockerfile instead of needing to add a file and another layer.

Comment: This will work in many circumstances, but won't be sufficient if there is a possibility that a given package already exists prior to attempting installation, such as for the case where you are trying to update the package version.

Comment: @dpritch Good point. I think this whole question is really trying to solve the wrong problem. A better question I think would be "What's the R equivalent of tools like Python's pip (and virtual environments)". I'm no R expert, far from it, but I think the answer might be 'packrat' https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-do-you-isolate-packages-environments-for-r-data-products-in-production/13004

Answer (score 6):

The R function `WithCallingHandlers()` lets us handle any warnings with an explicitly defined function.  For instance, we can tell the R to stop if it receives any warnings (and return the warning message as an error message).

```
withCallingHandlers(install.packages("notapackage"),
                    warning = function(w) stop(w))
```

I am guessing that this is not ideal, since presumably a package could install successfully but still throw a warning; but haven't encountered that case.  As Dirk suggests, testing `require` for the package is probably more robust.

Comment: That may do it.  On the missing package we get `stop()` invoked, next question is whether a failed build (missing headers, ...) wll get caught.

Comment: Yup, missing headers etc all throw a generic warning: e.g. `Warning message:
In install.packages("XML") :
installation of package 'XML' had non-zero exit status` occurs on `install.packages("XML")` on `debian-r-base` which lacks `libxml2`

Comment: `tryCatch` works here in place of `withCallingHandlers` as well

Answer (score 3):

try to install then look for warnings to stop the execution and return an error. also calls library() , just in case !

```
 install_or_fail <- function(package_name){ 

   tryCatch({install.packages(package_name, dependencies = TRUE) 
         library(package_name)}, 
         error = function(e){ print(e) }, 
         warning = function(w){
           catch <-
             grepl("download of package .* failed", w$message) ||
             grepl("(dependenc|package).*(is|are) not available", w$message) ||
             grepl("installation of package.*had non-zero exit status", w$message) ||
             grepl("installation of one or more packages failed", w$message)
           if(catch){ print(w$message)
             stop(paste("installation failed for:",package_name ))}}
         )

 }
```

inspired by : https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/install2.r

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. Just one comment: if the goal is to throw errors on failures, wouldn't the `error = function(e){ print(e) }` argument suppress those failures? I think you can just leave that argument out.

Comment: I added a similar solution based on this one to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73534778/5518304

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the quick comment:

```
R> AP <- available.packages()
R> "notapackage" %in% AP[,1]      # expected to yield FALSE
[1] FALSE
R> "digest" %in% AP[,1]           # whereas this should be TRUE
[1] TRUE
R>
```

Comment: I picked a bad minimal example.  We want a solution that throws an error when the install.packages() fails regardless of the cause (cannot compile, etc), not just the case of a missing package.

Comment: See `help(install.packages)` and check for return value. Methinks they promise you an unconditional `NULL` so I fear _no mas_ unless you preempt (as I suggested) or rewrite...

Comment: Correct, `install.packages` returns NULL no matter what.  I do not follow how I can preempt the various reasons package install fails...

Comment: The question I answered was concerned with the example of a *missing* package. I answered that. You since changed the scope and parameters of your question and now have a harder question on hand. From the top of my head you could *follow* the installation attempt with `require(pkg)` and report its status.  Sucky, but you gotta deal with the installer given ...

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Cameron Kerr's answer, here's another solution that would work in a `Dockerfile` (or at a unix command line) without needing to add an additional file/layer:

```
RUN R -e " \
   install_packages_or_die <- function (pkgs, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/') { \
   for (l in pkgs) {  install.packages(l, dependencies=TRUE, repos=repos); \
       if ( ! library(l, character.only=TRUE, logical.return=TRUE) ) { \
          stop ('ERROR: failed installing requested package \'',l,'\'') } } } ; \
   install_packages_or_die (pkgs= c('mime')); "

RUN R -e " \
   install_packages_or_die <- function (pkgs, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/') { \
   for (l in pkgs) {  install.packages(l, dependencies=TRUE, repos=repos); \
       if ( ! library(l, character.only=TRUE, logical.return=TRUE) ) { \
          stop ('ERROR: failed installing requested package \'',l,'\'') } } } ; \
   install_packages_or_die (pkgs= c('packagedoesnotexist')); "
```

**Note:** sometimes packages install dependencies after the requested package failed, and you'll still have to search the log to see what the actual error was.

Answer (score 0):

I've added another version that essentially tweaks @mnl's solution (which is in turn inspired by @dirk-eddelbuettel's `install_packages2` function) to collect and report all of the package build failures.

```
# `install.packages` unfortunately does not throw an error if package
# installation fails but rather a warning. So we check the warnings and promote
# the appropriate ones to errors. The regex conditions are taken from the
# `install_packages2` function in
# https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/install2.r
warns <- character(0L)
withCallingHandlers(
  expr = {
    install.packages(c("pk1", "pkg2", "etc"))
  }, warning = function(w) {
    catch <- (
      grepl("download of package .* failed", w$message)
      || grepl("(dependenc|package).*(is|are) not available", w$message)
      || grepl("installation of package.*had non-zero exit status", w$message)
      || grepl("installation of one or more packages failed", w$message)
    )
    if (catch) {
      warns <<- c(warns, w$message)
      invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
    }
  }
)
if (length(warns) >= 1L) {
  msg <- paste(warns, collapse = "\n")
  stop(msg)
}
```